# Tourist visa for baby born in the UK? (TIER2 parents)

Tags: uk-visa, children

My wife and I are under the TIER2 visa and we had a baby recently. First, we got her passport issued and a few weeks ago, we've applied for the dependent visa, that hasn't been yet issued (the deadline of 8 weeks is almost being hit).

The problem is that we wanted to go abroad on Christmas (we've bought the tickets already), but as per what I've seen, we will need her visa in order to enter the UK.

The question is: is it possible to go outside of the UK without her Visa/BRP and once are come back in, ask the officer to stamp her passport with a "tourist visa" and once we get her BRP, we sort it out?

Comment: No. The child is in no way a 'visitor' and the officer will not go along with kind of scheme. It's very likely you child's visa will come through at the 8 week mark.

Comment: @ouflak that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. The child is in no way a 'visitor' and the officer will not go along with that kind of scheme. It's very likely your child's visa will come through at the 8 week mark (if that is indeed the suggested time frame, couldn't track that down in the documentation).